# Improper Return Value using NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on a new feature for an existing iPhone application, and would like to create several new directories in the application's local "Documents" folder. I have successfully done this using the recommended method:

```
[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]
```

When reading the documentation for this method, I was intrigued by return values listed in Apple's official [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:):

> Return Value:
>   YES if the operation was successful **or already exists**, otherwise NO

Each time my application starts up, I would like to ensure that the directories are properly in place. I thought a clever way of doing this would be to call the **createDirectory:** method on each start and take advantage of the method's return value. If the directory was missing for some reason, it would be created. If the directory was already in place, the return value would still be **YES**. A **NO** return value could then be used as a flag for additional recovery/repair logic.

Unfortunately, I appear to be getting results inconsistent with Apple's documentation. The method is returning **NO** if the directory already exists - when Apple's docs say it should return **YES** in this case.

The following program demonstrates this behavior:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
bool testDirectoryCreated = NO;

testDirectoryCreated = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[fm currentDirectoryPath],@"TestDirectory"] 
                                                withIntermediateDirectories: NO 
                                                                 attributes: nil 
                                                                      error: NULL];

NSLog(@"TestDirectory Created: %@\n", (testDirectoryCreated ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

testDirectoryCreated = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[fm currentDirectoryPath],@"TestDirectory"] 
                                                withIntermediateDirectories: NO 
                                                                 attributes: nil 
                                                                      error: NULL];

NSLog(@"TestDirectory Created: %@\n", (testDirectoryCreated ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

[pool drain];

return 0;
```

}

When the program executes, it will print **YES** on the first createDirectory: call, and **NO** on the second call - when "TestDirectory" already exists.

Is this an error in Apple's documentation, or am I missing something?

Also, any other ideas for just validating the integrity of my directory structure? Is there a simple "directory exists" method I can call?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to get the convenience to also check if the directory exists with this method, you must pass TRUE to the withIntermediateDirectories: parameter.

This is stated in Apple's documentation

> In addition, if you pass NO for this parameter, the directory must not exist at the time this call is made.

Comment: Odd, my documentation states: "If YES, this method creates any non-existent parent directories as part of creating the directory in url. If NO, this method fails if any of the intermediate parent directories does not exist. This method also fails if any of the intermediate path elements corresponds to a file and not a directory." - makes me think it is wording from createDirectoryAtURL: - is the behavior different?

Answer (score 1):

It does seem odd to me that the return value would be YES, if the  directory already exists. I would have expected this return Value to only reflect success on creating the dir.  Which would be consistent to your returns.

As to your other question, you may want to look at **fileExistsAtPath:**  and **fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory**: under the NSFileManager.

Comment: Yes, it does seem odd that the method would return yes in the "already exists" case, but it seemed convenient for what I was doing. Apple's documentation seems to contradict itself - earlier in the method description, it states that the path at which you create the directory must not yet exist, yet its description of return values seems to indicate otherwise. Thanks for the other suggestions !